# Не понимаю что не так с Django, ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'bboard'

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Учу Django по учебнику, делаю все в точности как там, но появилась ошибка *"ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'bboard'"*
Переворошил все отредактированные файлы, перечитал все несколько раз в учебнике, так и не понял причины ошибки

**Отредактированная часть кода settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bboard.apps.BboardConfig',
]
```

**Код views.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse("Здecь будет выведен список объявлений.")
```

**Код urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from bЬoard.views import index 

urlpatterns = [
  path ( 'bboard/', index),  
  path ( 'admin/', admin. site. urls),
]
```

**Код apps.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BboardConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'bboard'
```

*Не знаю, поможет ли это в поиске ошибки, но для полноты ситуации добавлю что папка bboard была создана через командную строку, используя команду manage.py startapp bboard*

Comment: `bЬoard.views` у вас тут b и мягкий знак Ь

Comment: Боже, спасибо, я думал в терминале просто bboard так отображается